# using conditional where clauses in mysql select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, select

There is a stored procedure `sp_select_from_persons` in MySql.  And there are 3 parameters inside this procedure. `age, class, group`. These parameter values can be -1 or another value. And these parameters will be used in `where` clause.
Now I want to write where clause like that, if any value of these parameter is another than **-1** then append them into `where` clause. For example:
if age = -1, class = 7 and group = 5 then select query will be:

```
SELECT * FROM persons p WHERE p.class = class AND p.group = group;
```

or if age = 25, class = -1 and group = -1 then:

```
SELECT * FROM persons p WHERE p.age = 25;
```

and etc.

I don't want to use emnedded IF statements like below:

```
IF age > 0 THEN 
  IF class > 0 THEN
     IF group > 0 THEN
     SELECT * FROM persons p WHERE p.age = age AND p.class = class AND p.group = group;
     END IF
     ELSE ....... etc
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a single line query.... Try This

```
SELECT * FROM persons p 
WHERE p.age = case when age = -1 then p.age else age end
and p.class = case when class = -1 then p.class else class end
and p.group = case when group = -1 then p.group  else group end
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this also worked for me:

```
create procedure sp_my_proc(in p1 varchar(10), in p2 int)
    begin
        SELECT col1, col2 from my_table
         where if(p1 is null or length(trim(p1)) = 0, true, col1 = p1)
           and if(p2 = 0, true, col2 = p2);
    end
```

My requirement is that the stored proc is being called from a `Java/SpringFramework-based` back-end where passing null values to stored proc invocation is not accepted so values are set to empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the logical `or` operator to crate this behavior in a single statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM   persons p 
WHERE  (age < 0 OR p.age = age) AND 
       (class < 0 OR p.class = class) AND 
       (group < 0 OR p.group = group);
```

Comment: Should that be AND in `(age > 0 OR p.age = age)` otherwise it will always match if an age is passed in?

Comment: @NigelRen by bad - it's supposed to be "age **<** 0 OR p.age = age" - either you passed -1 (or you ignore `p.age`) or the age matches.

Comment: Select * from myTable where (Negative Conditions  OR Positive Conditions)  AND (Negative Conditions  OR Positive Conditions) ;